# SearchPhaseExecutionException with Basic Embedded Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I am trying out Elasticsearch with a basic Scala program, using the Java API:

```
object TestES {
  var node:Node = NodeBuilder.nodeBuilder.node
  var client:Client = node.client

  def insertDoc(id:String, doc:String) = {
    client.prepareIndex("myindex", "test", id).
           setSource(doc).execute.actionGet
  }

  def countHits(qry:String) = {
    client.prepareSearch("myindex").setTypes("test").
           setQuery(queryString(qry)).execute.actionGet.
           getHits.getTotalHits
  }

  def waitForGreen = client.admin.cluster.prepareHealth().
                     setWaitForGreenStatus.execute.actionGet

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    insertDoc("1", """{"foo":"bar"}""")
    //waitForGreen
    println(countHits("bar"))

    node.close
  }
}
```

This works, and the insert + query run in under one second. If I comment out the insert, I get the following exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.elasticsearch.action.search.SearchPhaseExecutionException:
Failed to execute phase [query], total failure;
shardFailures {[_na_][myindex][0]: No active shards}
```

If I enable the `waitForGreen` line, it works again, but takes over half a minute to run both lines.

This seems quite odd. Is inserting a document a must before running a query, or is there a better way?

Answer (score 0):

Inserting a document is not needed to run a query, but having the index created is required. 
When you insert a document and the index doesn't exist, it will be automatically created.

If you want to avoid document creation, you can create only the index using the API :

```
client.admin.indices.prepareCreate("myindex").execute.actionGet
```

Comment: My index does exist. It was created the first time I ran this (with `insertDoc`).